# Para que serve o ~ em expressão regular?

Tags: php, regex

Estou com o código:

```
function addhttp($url){

    if(!preg_match('~^(http)s?://~i', $url)){

        $url = 'http://'.$url;
    }

    return $url;

}
```

Ele add o HTTP caso a URL informada não contenha, mas o que estou com dúvida é na questão do **~** que tem no inicio e depois no fim **~i** . Queria saber pra que serve isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expressões regulares PCRE(Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) necessitam de  [delimitadores](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) que são um par de caracteres não alfanumericos onde um fica no início e outro no final. Também é comum o uso da barra `/` como delimitador caso sua regex precisa capturar alguma você precisa escapa-la.

```
 '~^(http)s?://~i    <---- modificador PCRE
--^           ^----
inicio         fim
```

A letra `i` ou qualquer outra após o demilitar é um dos [modificadores PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), o `i` significa que a expressão será analizada como case insensitive ou seja não diferencia maiusculas de minusculas que seria o equivalente a `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: O mesmo vale para o ~i ?

Comment: @AlissonAcioli O `i` é uma flag usada para indicar que a comparação deve ser case-**i**nsensitive, ou seja, *não* diferencia maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Comment: Entendi... Tentei fazer assim **/^(http)s?:///** e deu erro por causa da **/** . Por isso usar **~** ?

Comment: Só assim deu: **/^(http)s?:\/\//i**

Comment: Precisa escapar a barra se não ele entende que você fechou e abriu duas regexs. @AlissonAcioli

Comment: Entendido. Muito obrigado aos dois!! @rray